# swift - Put values of Dictionary inside NSArray into Array

Tags: swift, nsarray

I have an NSArray with dictionaries that look like this:

```
{
    count = 7;
    week = 4;
}

{
    count = 9;
    week = 5;
}
```

How do I turn these dictionaries inside the NSArray into two arrays that look like this:

```
weeks = [4, 5]
count = [7, 9]
```

I have tried: `let array = Array(arrayLiteral: results.valueForKey("month"))`

But just get this back

```
[(
    4,
    5
)]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap and conditional cast it to Int to extract your dictionary values as follow:

```
let nsArray = NSArray(array: [["count":7,"week":4],["count":9,"week":5]])

let weeks = nsArray.flatMap{$0["week"] as? Int}
let count = nsArray.flatMap{$0["count"] as? Int}

print(weeks)  // "[4, 5]"
print(count)  // "[7, 9]"
```

Comment: Leo, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!